# Where to copy Resharper external annotation XML files to be found by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-9.1

I have created a XML annotation file for one of my libraries and want to make it available for all my projects without needing to copy it in each project binary folder.

For what I have read this can be done by copying it into the Resharper installation folder but I have tried a few places without success.

I have copied it in the following folders:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14\ExternalAnnotations\MyCompany

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\vs14.0\Bin\ExternalAnnotations
```

The xml file has the exact same name as the dll that annotates, but xml extension. And the contents are like the follow:

```
<assembly name="Company.Tools.Libs.Logging">
  <member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteDebug(System.String,System.Object[])">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)" />
    <argument>"format"</argument>
  </member>
  <member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteInfo(System.String,System.Object[])">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)" />
    <argument>"format"</argument>
  </member>
  <member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteWarning(System.String,System.Object[])">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)" />
    <argument>"format"</argument>
  </member>
  <member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteError(System.String,System.Object[])">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)" />
    <argument>"format"</argument>
  </member>
  <member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteFatal(System.String,System.Object[])">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)" />
    <argument>"format"</argument>
  </member>
</assembly>
```

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

As @citizenmatt has said my xml was wrong, and the argument nodes need to be nested inside the attribute element. Doing this with a simple project I used to replicate the issue make it work, but that was by creating the external annotations in the same folder as the dll and with .ExternalAnnotation prefix.

I am still trying to find out where to copy it on my machine so its picked by Resharper without distributing it along the dll.

UPDATE 2:

After discussing with @citizenmatt I have decided to ship my annotations along the dll. He had a good point, adding it on the installation dir of Resharper will make them disappear in every new installation plus its not a very intuitive place. Also, I haven't been able to get VS to get my annotations from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I think it needs to be in a sub-folder of `ExternalAnnotations`. You'll also need to close and reopen your solution before it will be picked up.

You can also ship the file next to the .dll, as long as it ends with `.ExternalAnnotations.xml`, e.g. `foo.dll` would need `foo.ExternalAnnotations.dll`.

Alternatively, you can ship the annotations in an extension. This is packaged up as a nuget package with a custom file layout. You can see the community extensions project for an example of the [nuspec file](https://github.com/robv8r/resharper-annotations/blob/master/src/resharper90.nuspec) (if your assembly is a public assembly, you might even want to add a pull request!)

However, the example XML you've shown here is incorrect - the `argument` element needs to be a *child* of the `attribute` element. It's telling ReSharper how to build an argument that should be applied - the `ctor` attribute gives ReSharper the constructor (and the class), and then we need to pass arguments to that constructor - so each `argument` element needs to be a child of the `attribute` element. In other words:

```xml
<member name="M:Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.Interfaces.IBasicLogger.WriteDebug(System.String,System.Object[])">
<attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.StringFormatMethodAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
  <argument>format</argument>
</attribute>
```

Comment: Tried on "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\vs14.0\Bin\ExternalAnnotations\Company" without success (closing and opening VS afterwards). The extension options is interesting but I would like to just copy the file to a shared folder and got picked up by all solutions.

Comment: Have you had this xml working when it's side-by-side with the dll? You might want to try doing that, and have a look at the argument - I think you want it so that it's NOT quoted, so `<argument>format</argument>`.

Comment: Not even copying in the same folder my project references the dll from seems to work. I renamed it to: "Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.ExternalAnnotations.xml" while the dll is called: "Company.Tools.Libs.Logging.dll". The quotes on the parameter were generated by ReSharper internal tools (http://hadihariri.com/2009/06/26/resharpers-hidden-gem/) which I use to generate the annotation file

Comment: Did you reopen your solution after copying it in? If you can send me the assembly and xml, I'll take a look (matt.ellis at jet brains - happy to sign NDAs). But on the face of it, everything looks ok, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @citizenmatt. I cannot send you the actual assembly but I will try to create a new similar one and send that to you. Quite busy at work lately so it could take me a while though

Comment: Cool. Some other thoughts - the first parameter of these methods is called `format`, isn't it? And this will only work when calling the methods directly via `IBasicLogger`. It won't work if you call it through a concrete class (I think, 95% sure of that).

Comment: Oh, I think that could be then! I use a different interface that inherits from that one, I would try to add the annotation to the one I am actually using and let you know. Can you add that on the answer just in case it is the right thing? :)

Comment: Honestly, couldn't see the wood for the trees with this one - the XML was wrong! Sorry I didn't spot it sooner. I've updated the answer to show what it should be like.